# Installing/Configuring Hue with Apache frameworks

Tags: hadoop, configuration, installation, hue

Has anyone tried configuring [Hue](http://gethue.com/) with the frameworks from Apache and not with CDH. The [documentation](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.5.0/manual.html#_hadoop_configuration) says to set the `mapred.jobtracker.plugins` property to `org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.ThriftJobTrackerPlugin` and check the JT log files to make sure that the Thrift plugin has been loaded. But, I don't see anything related to Thrift in the JT log files. And, also looks like the `mapred.jobtracker.plugins` in not defined in the [mapred-site.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/packages/templates/conf/mapred-site.xml) for Hadoop 1.2.1 which is the latest stable release.

Answer (score 1):

Did you had the mapred.jobtracker.plugins to the mapred-site.xml? Hadoop support plugins since 1.2.0 so you should be good.

Comment: The documentation says to add the property in the mapred-site.xml. I gave an invalid class name for the same property and still I don't see any exception in the JT log file. Looks like it has not been included in Hadoop 1.2.1.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct Hadoop? The official support came in 0.23/1.2.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-461. Also did you copy the jar files?

Comment: As mentioned in the OP I used the 1.2.1 which the current stable release, let me try it out with 1.2.0.